# Mysql code is ok. Php fails to echo it. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

I am new in PHP. This code of mysql is 100% working in phpmyadmin. I am using `<?php echo $row['Rank'];?>` but I only get 1 for all students. Maybe I am bad in echoing things. Please help me.

```
Select Distinct regd, Roll_no, Name_of_Student, Test_date,
English, f_eng, Mizo, f_mz,  Hindi, f_hn,  Mathematics,  f_maths, SS, f_ss, Science, 
f_sc, score, fmscore, perc, Rank FROM (SELECT *, IF(@marks = (@marks := score), @auto, 
@auto := @auto + 1) AS Rank FROM
(SELECT regd, Roll_no, Name_of_Student, Test_date,
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'English', Mark_score, 0 ) ) AS English,
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'English', Full_mark, 0 ) ) AS f_eng, 
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Mizo', Mark_score, 0 ) ) AS Mizo,
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Mizo', Full_mark, 0 ) ) AS f_mz, 
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Hindi', Mark_score, 0 ) ) AS Hindi,
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Hindi', Full_mark, 0 ) ) AS f_hn, 
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Mathematics', Mark_score, 0 ) ) AS Mathematics, 
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Mathematics', Full_mark, 0 ) ) AS f_maths, 
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'SS', Mark_score, 0 ) ) AS SS,
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'SS', Full_mark, 0 ) ) AS f_ss, 
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Science', Mark_score, 0 ) ) AS Science,
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Science', Full_mark, 0 ) ) AS f_sc,
SUM(Full_mark) AS fmscore,
SUM(Mark_score) AS score, SUM(Mark_score)/SUM(Full_mark)*100 as perc FROM cxexam,
(SELECT @auto := 0, @marks := 0) AS init GROUP BY regd ORDER BY score DESC) t) AS result where Test_date between '2013-07-01' and '2013-07-31'
```

Here is the PHP part. It seems OK. It also echo everything correctly except that it does not output the Rank correctly. In the rank row it only displays  `1` as rank for all students. You can understand from the below code what I am trying to achieve. I really need your help. I know you guys are well familiar with such problem.

```
<table width="800" border="1" class="tablestyle" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="6">
<tr> 
    <th align="center" width="80">Roll No</th>
    <th align="center" width="100">Name_of_Student</th>
    <th align="center" width="40">English</th>
    <th align="center" width="55">Mizo</th>
    <th align="center" width="55">Hindi</th>
    <th align="center" width="55">Math</th>
    <th align="center" width="70">SS</th>
    <th align="center" width="40">Science</th>
     <th align="center" width="70">FM</th>
      <th align="center" width="70">MO</th>
      <th align="center" width="40">Percentage</th>
      <th align="center" width="40">Rank</th>
      <th align="center" width="40">Result</th>

</tr>
<?php 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
?>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['Roll_no'];?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $row['Name_of_Student'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['English'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['Mizo'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['Hindi'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['Mathematics'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['SS'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['Science'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['fmscore'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['score'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo number_format($row['perc'],0);?>%</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Rank']; ?></td>
    <td><?php 
    if ($row['English']/$row['f_eng']*100>=40 && $row['Mizo']/$row['f_mz']*100>=40 && $row['Hindi']/$row['f_hn']*100>=40 && $row['Mathematics']/$row['f_math']*100>=40 && $row['SS']/$row['f_ss']*100>=40 && $row['Science']/$row['f_sc']*100>=40)
   {
   echo "<font color=green>Passed</font>";
   }
   else 
   {
   echo "<font color=red>Failed</font>";
   }
   ?></td>

</tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're not a *write-my-code-for-me* service; show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @michealb956 I understand. I could produce the expected output in separate mysql statement. I just don't know how to add that in this mysql code. Since this is ties in ranking, it's little complex. I will show my code later. let me try what I could do.

Comment: @micheal956. here are my code. You can see from my codes that I have been trying hard and not expect everyone here to get my task done.

Comment: @Bill Karwin Can you help us?

Answer (score 0):

Can give just Overview to finish this Stuff.

```
$sql_q="<!--put your Query Here.-->";
$res=mysql_query($sql_q);

<!--Now Make a Table to Present all the Things-->

<table>
    <tr> 
        <th>English</th>
        <th>Mizo</th>
        <th>Hindi</th>
        <th>Math</th>
        <th>SS</th>
        <th>Science</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><!--Your Data for Each Columns--></td>
            <!-- Example to print Roll No-->
            <td><?php echo $row['Roll_no'];?></td>


    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I add the rank and result column? Also please show me how I should use the echo. I am new.

Comment: thanks again. please can you show me how to add rank and result columns.

Comment: <!--For Result Column-->


<td><?php $percentage=$row['Percentage']; if($percentage<33) {$result='Fail'}else{$result='pass'} echo $result;?></td>

Comment: Zual a: Have u got the solution.

Comment: thanks for helping. Your code is not displaying anything. I am using the following code of mine, and it is working. `<?php 
  if ($row['English']>=33 && $row['Mizo']>=33 && $row['Hindi']>=33 && $row['Mathematics']>=33 && $row['SS']>=33 && $row['Science']>=33)
       {
       echo "<font color=green>Passed</font>";
       }
       else 
       {
       echo "<font color=red>Failed</font>";
       }
       ?>` But I am not sure whether it will work in large data. Can you help me out to find the rank. You can read the question again.

Comment: @Zuala:Its nice to hear that u done that. But about Rank stuff u can also do that. That will be just proper use of IF Condition and Print that using ECHO..As u already done with Percentage calculation.. Just try..If not getting proper then ping me.

Comment: Thanks again. I can do it using separate mysql code and separate php code. I am trying to integrate that into this code. I will let you know later how I do.

Comment: @Zuala:That would be better.

Comment: my code is a bit long, I could not paste here. I pasted here http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/921 My code could not out anything. I don't know how to fix it. please help

Comment: please can you show me where my code is wrong. I can't figure it out.